# Prevent UIWebView from making 7 numbers into a hyperlink

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I put some data in a UIWebView and as part of my data, I have 7 numbers together.  The UIWebView makes the text be a hyperlink with the option to add to contact or copy the link.  Is there a way to disable that so the 7 numbers don't appear as a phone number?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick Google turns up the [UIWebView docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html), which say that you can alter the `dataDetectorTypes` property to disable this behavior. The possible values are listed in the [UIKit Data Types Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitDataTypesReference/Reference/reference.html) - you may want `UIDataDetectorTypeNone`.

Answer (score 3):

you can turn it off in HTML by add this meta in HTML:

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
```

the document is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008193-SW1)